# Integer from .plist

Tags: ios, properties, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I'm new to plists, and I really need to use one. What I have is a plist where different numbers are stored, under two dictionaries. I need to get that number which is stored, and make it an integer. This process will be run from a method called 'readPlist.

The plist is called 'properties.plist'. The first dictionary is called 'Enemies'. It contains various other dictionaries, which will have the name stored in the NSMutableString called 'SpriteType'. The name of the number will have the format 'L - %d', with the %d being an integer called 'LevelNumber'.

If possible, can someone give me the code on how to get that integer using the information, and the names of dictionaries above.

I have looked around at how to access plists, but the code that people have shown doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Too make it more understandable, this is my plist. What i want in an integer, called 'SpriteNumber' to be equal to the value of 'L - %d'

[image: properties.plist]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the contents of your plist into a dictionary (I won't tell you how to do it, but [this](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/) is the tutorial I refer to often), then it's a matter of getting the string out of the key for the level with `[[myDictionary objectForKey:@"key"]stringValue];`. Then, using of NSString's extremely helpful `-stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:` to get rid of the "L -" part and only get a numerical value.  Finally, get an integer from the string with `[myString intValue]`.

Comment: I just added an image, to make what i wanted slightly clearer.

Comment: Ah!  So the key would then be `L - %d` and the object would already be an integer.  That makes your life quite a bit easier, my friend.

Comment: Ok, so I have the code, but in the part:  

SpriteNumber = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"L - %d", LevelNumber] intValue]; 

I get an error, saying that 'Too many argumentsto method call, expected 1, have 2' on the LevelNumber.
 Do you know of a way to fix this?

Comment: You need to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"L -%d", [LevelNumber intValue]]`.

Answer (score 0):

well, the easiest way would be something like :

```
-(int) getMosquitoCountForLevel:(int) level {
    int mosquitoCount=0;
    NSString *gsFile = @"whateverFullyQualifiedFileNameYourPlistIs";
    NSDictionary* definitions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:gsFile];
    NSDictionary* mosquitos = [definitions objectForKey:@"Mosquito"];
    if(mosquitos) {
       NSString *levelKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"L - %d",level];
       NSNumber *mosquitoCountAsNumber = [mosquitos objectForKey:levelKey];
       if(mosquitoCountAsNumber) {
         mosquitoCount=[mosquitoCountAsNumber intValue];
       } else {
         CCLOGERROR(@"%@ - Mosquito definitions in %@ does not contain a en entry for level %@.",self.class,gsFile,levelKey);
       }
    } else {
      CCLOGERROR(@"%@ - file %@ does not contain a Mosquito dictionary.",self.class,gsFile);
    }
    return mosquitoCount;
}
```

this compiles but not tested with actual data.

Comment: And so the number that I want is called mosquitoCount?

Comment: yes, for example this method will return the integer 9 for levels 15,16, and 17, with the above plist